# Python parse xml to retrieve 'title' from data

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm trying to figure out a way to read in a URL contents with python and then parse the title into a variable.

Example of URL data being displayed/read in:

```
<subsonic-response xmlns="http://subsonic.org/restapi" status="ok" version="1.8.0" debug="true">
    <script id="FirebugLite" firebugIgnore="true" extension="Chrome"/>
    <song id="11450" parent="11042" title="30 Minutes Or Less (2011)" album="30 Minutes Or Less (2011)" isDir="false" created="2011-11-04T16:07:38" duration="4983" bitRate="1536" size="3521040154" suffix="mkv" contentType="video/x-matroska" isVideo="true" path="30 Minutes Or Less (2011)/30 Minutes Or Less (2011).mkv" transcodedSuffix="flv" transcodedContentType="video/x-flv"/>
</subsonic-response>
```

Is there a way to get the data from the title feild? So in a variable I would end up with '30 Minutes Or Less (2011)'

I've got the flowing code now but having troubles getting it to work.

```
import urllib, urllib2
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
url = 'https://myurl.com'
root = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
tester = ElementTree.parse(root)
elem = ElementTree.find("title")
print elem
```

Error:
TypeError: unbound method parse() must be called with ElementTree instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: You should use an XML parser. Are you sure you have done enough research before asking? Please choose a parsing library (the built-in one or `lxml`, as suggested above) and refer to its documentation.

Comment: added what i have but getting this error - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getElementsByTagName'

Comment: I would suggest using [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#) in the Python Standard Library. Your error sounds like you haven't parsed the file into an ElementTree instance, and instead are trying to use the raw character data in it.

Comment: Ok, I'm out of ideas trying to figure this out. I cannot find a good example anywhere to figure out how to parse a url's data to return the text from the element called title